# Can you call an executable from a Owin self hosted Web API restfull service

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, exe, owin

I am trying to set up a self hosted OWIN webservice that spins up an executable process.

The same code I use to calls up the executbal as a simple test console application will not call it up from my self hosted service instance.  I don't see an exception I don't see any logs of any kind.  Not sure what could possibly be wrong.  I am starting to think this is not allowed.

```
        [Route("startApplication/{application}/{parameters}/{workingDirectory}")]
        public IEnumerable<String> startApplication(string application, string parameters, string workingDirectory) {
        logger.logInfo("startApplication restfully called");
        RunResults runResults = new RunResults {
            ...
        };
        application = new Uri(application).LocalPath;      
        try {
            if (File.Exists(application)) {
                using (Process proc = new Process()) {
                    logger.logInfo(String.Format("Attempting to start application: {0}", application));
                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = application;
                    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;
                    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    proc.OutputDataReceived += (o, e) => runResults.Output.Append(e.Data).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    proc.ErrorDataReceived += (o, e) => runResults.Output.Append(e.Data).Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    proc.Start();
                    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();                        
                    proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
                    proc.WaitForExit();
                    runResults.ExitCode = proc.ExitCode;
                    logger.logInfo(String.Format("Application has started: {0}", application));
                }
            }
            else {
        ...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
        return new string[] { "Hello", "world", "jive", "turkeys" };
    }
```

I am probably not doing something right.
I know what you are thinking... This is insecure.  It is an internal app that will only be accessed by people in the right security groups.  If you aren't in, you can't call this controller.  Also It will be protected by what I call triangle authentication.  The details of which are besides the point of this post.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any thoughts gentlemen?  This seems like a little obscure of a topic?  Maybe there is no answer?

Answer (score 0):

In this article the writer developed a windows service which is having the full OS capabilities without security restriction like web servers and then embedded a self host web API in order to communicate with it, very neat approach and clean as there is enough room of isolation of each of the technologies used. Hopefully it would answer you questions 
[link](http://www.bfcamara.com/post/52138881551/running-a-desktop-app-with-angularjs-served-from-a)